# Update table using equal percentages of each value in IN statement

Tags: sql

I'm looking to write an update statement that is similar to this...

```
UPDATE top (15) percent magTable    
SET Name= 'Issue'
WHERE magID IN ('TNE', 'TBB', 'DTT', 'HTF')
```

But I need it to take 15% of **each** of the values in the IN statement. I'm looking for a more elegant way to write this than to separate it into 4 different update statements (one per magID).

I'm fairly new at this (which is probably obvious) :D Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: 15% "randomly"??  ordered? What is the end game here are you doing some sort of sample analysis?

Comment: Well I don't get it too. I can provide you a query which will do this. But what is the reason behind it? I would avoid it, if possible.

Comment: There is a set percentage of these magID's that are provided each week to an outside vendor.   I wouldn't mind separating them if there were only truly 4 but there are a lot more update statements that use this similar syntax and changes occur often so a more simplified way to write this would be extremely helpful.  Sorry if I sound completely ignorant. Appreciate the help tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you probably could, but I don't think it's worth the trouble, especially for just four lines of code. I've had to perform many more updates just by copying each line any making a small modification. The advantage is that you can see exactly what you're doing, whereas with a more complex set of code, you might not be able to follow it as easily.

```
 UPDATE top (15) percent magTable SET Name= 'Issue' WHERE magID = 'TNE'
 UPDATE top (15) percent magTable SET Name= 'Issue' WHERE magID = 'TBB'
 UPDATE top (15) percent magTable SET Name= 'Issue' WHERE magID = 'DTT'
 UPDATE top (15) percent magTable SET Name= 'Issue' WHERE magID = 'HTF'
```

Also, as other people have mentioned, using TOP without ORDER BY will give you the top 15% as stored in the table, which is probably just based on your import file. It's not a random sample unless you randomized the input file.

Comment: Even if you randomize the input, then it is not a so-called "random" sample. The SQL specification gives *no guarantee* of any kind of order when returning rows (and it shouldn't, given that a table is based on a relation, which has no order). You *may* find an order in some DBMS products but even here there is no guarantee.

Comment: True. Best practice for selecting randomly would be `ORDER BY NEWID()`, right?

Comment: Depends on how you define randomly. If you are OK with pseudo-random, then if your DBMS system supports the NEWID() function (e.g. Microsoft SQL Server), it could do the job (but NEWID() isn't what most stats folks would call "statistically random"). Have a look at Ebarr's answer on the DBA SE: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/955/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-random-ordering